# Python KeyError in dict.copy

Tags: python

My function:

```
def adjustDict(d):
    new = {}
    for word in d:
        lword = word.lower()
        possible = getPossible(lword)
        new[lword] = new.get(lword, 0) + d[word]
        for pword in possible:
            new[pword] = new.get(pword, 0) + d.get(pword, 0)
    nnew = new.copy()
    for word in nnew:
        print(word, word in new, word in nnew)
        if new[word] == 0: # KeyError
            del new[word]
        else:
            possible = getPossible(word)
            max_freq = max([new.get(pword, 0) for pword in possible] + [new[word]])
            for pword in possible:
                if 0 < new.get(pword, 0) < max_freq:
                    del new[pword]
    return new
```

I am getting a `KeyError` in the commented line, which I think should not happen because nnew is just a copy of new. `Why does a key appear in the copy of a dict but not the dict itself?` I didn't do anything related to asychronization.

This is the error message:

```
kazan's True True
kazan True True
kazan' True True
early True True
ear True True
earle False True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seaky\Desktop\Docs\UCSB\3rd\2019 Winter\CS 165A\MP1\main.py", line 102, in <module>
    write('training_pos.json', adjustDict(readJson('training_pos.json')))
  File "C:\Users\Seaky\Desktop\Docs\UCSB\3rd\2019 Winter\CS 165A\MP1\main.py", line 52, in adjustDict
    if new[word] == 0:
KeyError: 'earle'
```

Comment: `earle False True`, "earle" is not there in the "new" dict

Comment: @Jeril I know. But why? Why is it in the `new.copy()`?

Comment: did you try copy.deepcopy [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)?

Comment: [link](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/be-careful-with-using-dict-to-create-a-copy). Hope this helps!.

Comment: @Jeril No. It is unnecessary. No matter what copy it is, 'earle' should not be in the copy.

Comment: @bumblebee Page not found...

Comment: @SeakyLuo updated it!.

Comment: I think it may be because you're deleting items from the dict whilst you're iterating over it.  Don't do that -- it can lead to very odd behavior such as you're seeing here.  (Yes, I see you're iterating over `nnew` and deleting from `new`, but `nnew` is a _shallow copy_, which means some linkage to `new` is retained.)

Comment: @JohnGordon But I am iterating through its copy and earle has never appeared before.

Comment: I updated my comment.  But I must admit I'm not totally confident of this explanation -- that's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Try adding a print statement in the two cases where you call `del new[...]` to print the key being deleted, and see if it's the same key that has the error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I guess you are right. I just tried `print('earle' in new)` before second for loop and it was there but somehow disappeared in the for loop.

Comment: Maybe you delete it in the `else` branch before you reach it.

Comment: @stovfl I am not removing a dict from a list. My question is entirely different.